# Word dictionary not getting all the words

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary folder which stores a list of dictionaries such as "Anger", "Care" etc.
For instance, i have a post on facebook that goes "I am sullen, irked, pertulent."
In my anger dictionary, i have the 3 words sullen, irked, pertulent.
When i run my word count program, it doesn't seem to be able to detect all the words accurately. To be more specific, my word count dictionary will detect that sullen and irked has occurred once, but pertulent none.

Is this problem caused by my regex?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace empTRUST
{
    class FBWordCount
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> countWordsInStatus(string status, string[] dictArray)
        {
            var words = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // local word dictionary is created here
            foreach (var dictEntry in dictArray)
            {
                var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
                string smallDictEntry = dictEntry.ToLower();
                foreach (Match match in wordPattern.Matches(status))
                {
                    if (match.ToString() == smallDictEntry)
                    {
                        int currentCount = 0;
                        words.TryGetValue(match.Value, out currentCount);

                        currentCount++;
                        words[match.Value] = currentCount;  // local word dictionary adds new word count
                    }
                }
            }
            return words;   // returns local word dictionary to receiving end
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @SamuelLee I am happy to see that you have started to focus in solving the problems step by step. Just a quick comment (as far as I know what you are doing this for), bear in mind that dictionaries are fine for small sizes but consume too much memory to deal with all what you want. You will have to rely on a database or a set of temporary files to store all the categories. For example, you can adapt the answer given by p.s.w.g to your situation by calling iteratively this function: for loop going through all the lists (stored in DB or file) and passing the required words as arguments.

Comment: @SamuelLee example of my last proposal (run out of space): foreach (curListWords in allListWords){ tempDict = countWordsInStatus(inputString, curListWords)} -> each tempDict will store the given matches for the corresponding category. As you can see, this would provoke an elevanted number of dictionaries (additionally to the aforementioned memory problems) and thus you might have to come up with a different approach. I am sure that in this way you would learn and would maximise the efficiency of the system. This is right way through. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This whole method can be replaced with a single Linq query. Try this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> countWordsInStatus(string status, string[] dictArray)
{
    var wordPattern = new Regex(@"\w+");
    return 
        (from Match m in wordPattern.Matches(status)
         where dictArray.Contains(m.Value)
         group m by m.Value)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count(),
            StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var results = countWordsInStatus(
    "I am sullen, irked, petulant.", 
    new[] { "sullen", "irked", "petulant" });
// { { "sullen", 1 }, 
//   { "irked", 1 }, 
//   { "petulant", 1 } }
```